# place image button over the image background on android

Tags: android-image, android

in my app i have a background image and need to place an image button at the specified location of the background image.i did by using frame layout with  `android:layout_gravity`,`layout_alignBottom` and `marginLeft and right` properties. please refer image no :1

i set it for one emulator and it works but i get  wrong when launch other emulator of different size  so how to set image view over a background image so that imageview not changes its position for any size of screen.

Is there any possibilities to  trigger action find by touching image button on the screen(both background image and image button combined as single image - please refer Image no 2)
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of problem, I would think that the best solution in order not to have problem with the screen sizes/densities would be to have different images for the play phase, stop etc.

Thus having: 
microphone with play button: 1 image
microphone with stop button: 1 image
microphone with play selected button: 1 image

Etc. and handling the user events.

Hope this helps!